# How can I get Smart-Table to work with json objects from a restful api

Tags: angularjs, json, smart-table

It appears that Smart-table by Lorenzo Fox works only with a straight forward data array. Is it possible for it to work with data objects which is produced by the following code:

```
    var getList = function () {
        return $http.get(webapi + "vw_C1Verify")
                    .then(function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
    };
```

Thanks
Paul

Comment: what do you mean? you get a JSON string instead of an object/array from `$http.get` ?

Comment: I understand your confusion, I was hoping to be able to post a couple of images, but apparently no, so I will try to explain.

Comment: If I use a straight json data file, then when I check my program in Chrome's developer tools I get the following when inspecting the data object: Array[9] followed by each individual element that shows the data. And Smart-table displays a length of 9. All Good.

Comment: But when I go to the database the following shows up while inspecting the element: Object followed by config: Object data: Array[693] followed by [0 ...99]... 0 Object which then displays the data. Smart-table thinks the length is 0.

Comment: BTW svarog - thanks for responding.

Comment: I think the "Array[9]" are what your smart table pagination shows on the current visible page. it won't show everything because the pagination uses a filter when displaying the rows. 
either way, can you reproduce the problem using a [small example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it on a scratch pad like [plunker](https://plnkr.co/)